# How to make a surface plot of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a nice DataFrame `df` where my X's are the rows, my Y's are the columns, and my Z's correspond to `df.loc[x, y]`:
[image]

I just want to make a surface plot of this. So far I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = df.index
y = df.columns
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

zs = np.array(df)
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

ax.set_xlabel(df.index.name)
ax.set_ylabel(df.columns.name)
ax.set_zlabel('Approximation')
plt.show()
```

But my result looks choppy and disjointed:

[image]

I think that the issue is how I'm making the plot, not the data. Am I doing something wrong here? I feel like reshaping the array is messing up the relationship between x's, y's, and z's, but I have tried all of np.reshape's ordering parameters.

Comment: Did you try `Z = df.values`? Although I do think that the issue is **indeed your data**, not how you plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish I could provide a more interesting answer, but it is probably just that your data has noise that is reflected in your surface plot.

I recreated some similar sinusoidal data to yours, added a little but not too much error, and the result is similarly choppy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


def my_func(x, y):
    return np.sin(x**2 + y**2)

x = np.linspace(0, 3, 61)
y = np.linspace(0, 3, 61)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# add some error to our function: for f(x,y) in the range of [-1,1]
# the noise has a standard deviation of 1/25 = 0.04
# which is close to the spacing in the mesh grid so it's noticeable
Z = my_func(X, Y) + np.random.standard_normal((len(x), len(y)))/25

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Approximation')
plt.show()
```

[image]